# Portable Dropbox/Google Drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, dropbox, google-drive, cloud-storage, portable-apps

I am planning to buy a new external harddisk, which will hold my project files using XAMPP Portable, my contacts, documents etc, as this thing is dealing with sensitive data, and I cannot rely on a single backup, I thought to sync with Dropbox/Google Drive, but I don't see any way to install these apps on an external drive.

I searched on Google but didn't found any help related to this, is there anyway I can make Dropbox/Google Drive portable?

---

As commented, I don't want the backups to be manual, as soon as I attach the drive with the PC, I want something that will be installed on my external drive, and as soon as I execute the application from that drive, it should sync the folders assigned to be synced with the cloud storage service. Because I can use this drive on any machine.

Comment: You can access them both using a simple browser and do the backups yourself... Can you expand more on what are you doing?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Updated my question :)

Comment: Thanks, much clearer. Any particular OS?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Only Windows 7 and higher ...

Comment: I found [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/auto-backup-website-dropbox/) maybe it will help with your specific problem. [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVBqiIoO7S4) may also help.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard the first link which you've provided is to sync the projects I've hosted online, other I will check out soon :) thanks again

Comment: If in the end, one of these links helps you, feel free to write an answer detailing how you did it, as to help other people with the same problem.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard sure, am constantly researching on this topic...

Comment: There's something called [DropboxPortableAHK](http://nionsoftware.com/dbpahk/overview).

Comment: @martineau You should post this as a full answer. Please include the reason why this (and all other) portable version [have to stick with version 1.1.45](http://nionsoftware.com/dbpahk/faq). I am now using this software for many years without any problems. You can even run multiple portable dropbox applications at once

Comment: @Mr.Alien DropboxAHK is perfect for your situation. I have the exact same setup with my external USB drive which I connect & sync at work and home

Comment: @nixda wait for few mins, will try, if it does what I want, I will let you know, please post it as an answer later and I will accept if it does the job :) thanks

Comment: @nixda: Sounds to me like you should post an answer suggesting it.

Comment: @martineau sorry, didn't saw it was you who suggested :)

Comment: @martineau I used that, but didn't quiet get it working, as installation seems weird, also it is not well documented, also I don't think its secure as it installs a dropbox copy on the local, so I don't want if it leaves any file on any pc, as I mentioned, am dealing with sensitive data here

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I'm not surprised -- as the whole approach seemed somewhat fragile, IMO. There are a few others out there, [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/) for example looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DropboxPortableAHK](http://nionsoftware.com/dbpahk/overview).

The beta version (v1.6.8.14) works with the more recent versions of Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

A little off topic, but if you are storing "sensitive" information you should consider encrypting your data locally before floating it up to the cloud.  TrueCrypt is a popular cross platform solution...

Or, you can just use a "cloud drive" service that is configurable (ie: you can control which files and folders sync, not just a dumb "drive" folder in your profile) and has client-side encryption built in. I've had great success with SpiderOak - 2GB for free + more for referrals.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly deviating answer based on your interest of portable secure storage that is backed up to cloud.

With sensitive data, the primary storage should be closer to you, rather than on the cloud.
There is, however, a good reason to keep a backup on the cloud too.

To that end, SanDisk has a a new solution (hence maybe a tad overpriced & available as 16GB/32GB only):
[SanDisk Connect Wireless Flash Drive](http://www.sandisk.com/products/wireless/flash-drive/)
<sup>(there are probably other similar things out there too)</sup>

```
 1. Store, share, and stream files across multiple mobile devices 
 2. 8 simultaneous device connections, 3 media streams 
 3. Works with iPad iPhone, iPod touch, Kindle Fire and Android™ devices 
 4. No cables router, or Internet connection needed 
 5. Provides up to 4 hours of wireless streaming per charge
 6. Wi-Fi Password Protection (WPA2)
 7. Download the SanDisk Wireless Flash Drive app for easy access
```

The idea would be to carry this device in your pocket at all times
and from some personal machines deemed 'safe' by you,
synchronize the data to your desired cloud service.
You then never have to worry about where the cloud apps retain intermediate data.